# How do I create events for the buckets in s3 using nodejs or from lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I wish to create s3 event from nodejs lambda function to to call another lambda function.

for example-> I have a lambda function test1 that creates s3 bucket and attaches the event to the bucket such that on the occurence of the event it call some different lambda function.

Problem -> I can create the lambda function to create an s3 bucket but I am not able to find create event method in AWS S3 documentation to implement this.

Comment: There is no 'S3 bucket created event'. However, your code is creating the bucket so why not simply immediately do the work that you want to be done when a bucket is created? Or alternatively, if you must do it via a second Lambda function, then simply invoke the second Lambda directly from the first Lambda right after you create the bucket?

Comment: After creaking bucket through lambda I am wish to attach event to that bucket. I am not able to find the s3 createvent or attachevent method for javascript to create or attach event to bucket.

Comment: Use putBucketNotificationConfiguration to enable notification of specific events for an S3 bucket.

Answer (score 2):

It is called BucketNotificationConfiguration in s3.

Refer

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketNotificationConfiguration-property

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTnotification.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html